# Fastest way to convert bytes to unsigned int

Tags: c++, performance, byte, memory-bandwidth

I have an array of bytes (`unsigned char *`) that must be converted to integer. Integers are represented over three bytes. This is what I have done

```
//bytes array is allocated and filled
//allocating space for intBuffer (uint32_t)
unsigned long i = 0;
uint32_t number;
for(; i<size_tot; i+=3){
    uint32_t number = (bytes[i]<<16) | (bytes[i+1]<<8) | bytes[i+2];
    intBuffer[number]++;
}
```

This piece of code does its jobs well but it is incredibly slow due to the three accesses in memory (especially for big values of `size_tot`, in the order of `3000000`). Is there a way to do it faster and increase performance?

Comment: Are you sure you want to overwrite `number` each time, and only 3 bytes are one integer?

Comment: Unless you're running this on a CPU with no cache and no prefetcher, this code will not generate a lot of real memory reads. Is there something you're not showing us? (Like you're not actually overwriting `number` a few 100k times?)

Comment: And, do you still need the byte data after converting?

Comment: Why do you need `for` loop when you are converting to just one 4 byte integer ? What is `size_tot` ?

Comment: @Nick size_tot is eg. 3000000, it's in the question.

Comment: @deviantfan , yes I'm sure.I overwrite it because in the for loop I fill an integer buffer and I do not use it again . I didn't post it because it was useless for my question

Comment: @J.kol That integer-buffer-filling would be interesting too...

Comment: That's a really weird cyclic addition thingy you've got there. And the problem most likely isn't the read or the conversion but the random writes.

Comment: @VaughnCato I edited my code with the answer below, in this way there is no more problem of initialization

Comment: @J.kol While there is some potential to make the number calculation faster (probably), I too think that the array indexing may be the main problem. Is there some purpose behind the values? Maybe there is a better algorithm?

Comment: @Gernot1976 Wrong (for both little/big endian architecture)

Comment: @J.kol Check the values too, because they are not correct. Don't use this memcpy call.

Comment: @deviantfan thanks,  you are right

Comment: Depending on the distribution of the numbers there may be a benefit to implementing `intBuffer` as some kind of sparse matrix.

Comment: @deviantfan no there is not a particular purpose, thery are random number and I have to count them and build an histogram. I do not know in which order they could arrive

Comment: @deviantfan a parallel/thread version would be complicated because I have to lock each time each single access to the intBuffer. What do you think?

Comment: @J.kol You don't need to lock it each time if you have separate intBuffer for each thread, which are added after the threads are done. But as your byte array is about 3MB and each intBuffer about 16MB, I don't think this will be better.

Comment: @J.kol About the calculation part, try avoiding the shifts. For little endian: `*((unsigned char *)(&number)+2)=bytes[0];*((unsigned char *)(&number)+1)=bytes[1];*((unsigned char *)(&number))=bytes[2];` (this is like Gernots deleted comment but corrected). Maybe it helps a little bit...

Comment: @deviantfan: FYI: I tried that approach, but it was much slower than the original.  This is with g++ 5.1, -O3.  The time was about the same as using `memcpy()`.

Comment: Just a thought, but you could use multiplication: `number = (unsigned int)byte[i] * 0x00010101;`

Comment: Seems like the best way would be to read a reasonably-sized integer (eg. `uint64`), swap the endianness if needed and shift/mask out 18 bits at a time. Unroll the loop 3x (so you're reading 3 `uint64`s, or 8 3-byte numbers at a time) to deal with edge cases.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer is almost always:

*Write correct code, enable optimisations, trust your compiler.*

given:

```
void count_values(std::array<uint32_t, 256^3>& results,
                  const unsigned char* from,
                  const unsigned char* to)
{
    for(; from != to; from  = std::next(from, 3)) {
        ++results[(*from << 16) | (*std::next(from, 1) << 8) | *(std::next(from,2))];
    }
}
```

compiled with `-O3`

Yields (explanatory comments inlined):

```
__Z12count_valuesRNSt3__15arrayIjLm259EEEPKhS4_: ## @_Z12count_valuesRNSt3__15arrayIjLm259EEEPKhS4_
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    jmp LBB0_2
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_1:                                 ## %.lr.ph
                                        ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_2 Depth=1
# dereference from and extend the 8-bit value to 32 bits
    movzbl  (%rsi), %eax
    shlq    $16, %rax            # shift left 16
    movzbl  1(%rsi), %ecx        # dereference *(from+1) and extend to 32bits by padding with zeros
    shlq    $8, %rcx             # shift left 8
    orq %rax, %rcx               # or into above result 
    movzbl  2(%rsi), %eax        # dreference *(from+2) and extend to 32bits
    orq %rcx, %rax               # or into above result
    incl    (%rdi,%rax,4)        # increment the correct counter
    addq    $3, %rsi             # from += 3
LBB0_2:                                 ## %.lr.ph
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    cmpq    %rdx, %rsi           # while from != to
    jne LBB0_1
## BB#3:                                ## %._crit_edge
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Notice that there is no need to stray away from standard constructs or standard calls. The compiler produces perfect code.

To further prove the point, let's go crazy and write a custom iterator that allows us to reduce the function to this:

```
void count_values(std::array<uint32_t, 256^3>& results,
                  byte_triple_iterator from,
                  byte_triple_iterator to)
{
    assert(iterators_correct(from, to));
    while(from != to) {
        ++results[*from++];
    }
}
```

And here is a (basic) implementation of such an iterator:

```
struct byte_triple_iterator
{
    constexpr byte_triple_iterator(const std::uint8_t* p)
    : _ptr(p)
    {}

    std::uint32_t operator*() const noexcept {
        return (*_ptr << 16) | (*std::next(_ptr, 1) << 8) | *(std::next(_ptr,2));
    }

    byte_triple_iterator& operator++() noexcept {
        _ptr = std::next(_ptr, 3);
        return *this;
    }

    byte_triple_iterator operator++(int) noexcept {
        auto copy = *this;
        _ptr = std::next(_ptr, 3);
        return copy;
    }

    constexpr const std::uint8_t* byte_ptr() const {
        return _ptr;
    }

private:

    friend bool operator<(const byte_triple_iterator& from, const byte_triple_iterator& to)
    {
        return from._ptr < to._ptr;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const byte_triple_iterator& from, const byte_triple_iterator& to)
    {
        return from._ptr == to._ptr;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const byte_triple_iterator& from, const byte_triple_iterator& to)
    {
        return not(from == to);
    }

    friend std::ptrdiff_t byte_difference(const byte_triple_iterator& from, const byte_triple_iterator& to)
    {
        return to._ptr - from._ptr;
    }

    const std::uint8_t* _ptr;
};

bool iterators_correct(const byte_triple_iterator& from,
                       const byte_triple_iterator& to)
{
    if (not(from < to))
        return false;
    auto dist = to.byte_ptr() - from.byte_ptr();
    return dist % 3 == 0;
}
```

Now what to we have?

- an assert to check that our source is indeed exactly the correct length (in debug build)
- an output structure that is guaranteed to be the right size

But what's it done to our object code? (compile with `-O3 -DNDEBUG`)

```
    .globl  __Z12count_valuesRNSt3__15arrayIjLm259EEE20byte_triple_iteratorS3_
    .align  4, 0x90
__Z12count_valuesRNSt3__15arrayIjLm259EEE20byte_triple_iteratorS3_: ## @_Z12count_valuesRNSt3__15arrayIjLm259EEE20byte_triple_iteratorS3_
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    jmp LBB1_2
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB1_1:                                 ## %.lr.ph
                                        ##   in Loop: Header=BB1_2 Depth=1
    movzbl  (%rsi), %eax
    shlq    $16, %rax
    movzbl  1(%rsi), %ecx
    shlq    $8, %rcx
    orq %rax, %rcx
    movzbl  2(%rsi), %eax
    orq %rcx, %rax
    incl    (%rdi,%rax,4)
    addq    $3, %rsi
LBB1_2:                                 ## %.lr.ph
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    cmpq    %rdx, %rsi
    jne LBB1_1
## BB#3:                                ## %._crit_edge
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Answer: **nothing** - it's just as efficient.

The lesson? No *really*! Trust your compiler!!!

Comment: I think your answer is basically right, but "trust your compiler" is overstating it a bit.  Although it is pretty rare, I've found many cases where some non-straightforward code was faster than the straightforward code. It may be more correct to say "Don't assume you can do tricks that will improve performance."

Comment: @VaughnCato I hear you, and of course in 30 years of writing code I have sometimes had to hand-craft code too. But most of those times were over 15 years ago. These days it's a last resort - when the correct algorithm has been selected, implemented elegantly and correctly, there are no other possible performance bottlenecks (like I/O, cache misses, missed opportunities to parallelise etc.), and the users are still telling me that the program is slow... only then is it time to roll your sleeves up and second-guess the compiler. Why pay the maintenance cost of custom code if we don't need to?

Comment: "_Trust your compiler!!!_" - Agreed, but since I encountered `uint var / 2` to be slower than `uint var >> 1` (years ago..), I lost a bit of confidence. While compilers are getting better, sometimes we might want to try and help them a bit (and in some cases compilers aren't even allowed to optimize certain parts).

Comment: @Danny_ds the great thing about using open source compilers is that if the performance can be improved, we either simply file a bug report or submit a patch. In this way compilers get *really good* *really fast*. The case you mention is certainly surprising. Compilers have been optimising multiplication and division by powers of two since I first learned C in the 80s. Does it still happen?

Comment: Well.. I'm somewhat stuck to Windows (planning to do some programming on Linux asap) - it was with Visual Studio and the standard MS compiler. I was surprised too, looked at the assembly, and there it was: division! (with optimizations on). Seems to be fixed now though. And it is certainly amazing what compilers can do these days.

Comment: @Danny_ds My heart froze at "Microsoft". You have my sympathy, although Herb Sutter has made great strides in dragging them into the 21st century. You can get a build of clang for windows, and certainly there is a build of gcc in cygwin and msys if you want to experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your sympathy Richard :) I'm installing a new system and will try all of them (including on Linux) - maybe the Intel compiler as well.

Comment: Try your example in C# and then compare the MSIL jitted asm. You will cry as the JIT doesn't have enough context to properly optimise your code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do a count of all the distinct values (your code: `intBuffer[number]++;`) (with intBuffer having 2^24 items), you could try to do some [**loop unrolling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling):

Instead of:

```
for(; i<size_tot; i+=3){
    uint32_t number = (bytes[i]<<16) | (bytes[i+1]<<8) | bytes[i+2];
    intBuffer[number]++;
}
```

do:

```
for(; i<size_tot; i+=12){   // add extra ckeck here..

    intBuffer[(bytes[i]<<16)   | (bytes[i+1]<<8) | bytes[i+2]]++;
    intBuffer[(bytes[i+3]<<16) | (bytes[i+4]<<8) | bytes[i+5]]++;
    intBuffer[(bytes[i+6]<<16) | (bytes[i+7]<<8) | bytes[i+8]]++;
    intBuffer[(bytes[i+9]<<16) | (bytes[i+10]<<8) | bytes[i+11]]++;
}
// Add a small loop for the remaining bytes (no multiple of 12)
```

This would allow the cpu to **execute multiple instructions in one clock cycle** (make sure to set compiler optimization at highest level).

You also need an extra check for the last part of `bytes`.

Check out [Instruction Pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining).

> **Instruction pipelining** is a technique that implements a form of **parallelism** called instruction-level parallelism within a single processor. **It therefore allows faster CPU throughput (the number of instructions that can be executed in a unit of time) than would otherwise be possible at a given clock rate**. The basic instruction cycle is broken up into a series called a pipeline. Rather than processing each instruction sequentially (finishing one instruction before starting the next), each instruction is split up into a sequence of steps **so different steps can be executed in parallel and instructions can be processed concurrently** (starting one instruction before finishing the previous one).

**Update**:

> but it is incredibly slow

Actually, for 3MB this should be somewhat instant, even with your original code (considering the data is already cached). How is `bytes` defined? Could it be that `operator[]` is doing some extra bounds checking?

Comment: are you suggesting a sort of loop unrolling? I think that this thing is done by hardware optimization or compiler I do not know... and I dont want to say more because I'm not an expert in this topic ;)

Comment: @J.kol - Yes, that's what I said in my answer :) Not sure the compiler would do that automatically, because you are reusing `number` each time. You could as well do a quick test with your compiler and data. (will also depend on the cpu of course).

Comment: @J.kol - But keep in mind that in your code you are making some kind of histogram. If you need a list of all the integers, you would have to change your code. (but it seems you might be reading in RGB-values, so a histogram could make sense here).

Comment: @J.kol - _"The proof of the cake is in the eating"_ :) I would love to hear if it makes any difference on your system. I don't think the compiler would 'unroll' `number` by itself. Speed gain will depend on the type of cpu you have (and compile for) though.

Comment: FYI: I did a timing test with your loop unrolling with g++ 5.1, -O3.  It may be helping slightly, but the difference is within the measurement noise.

Comment: @VaughnCato - Thanks for the info. Just curious: how was the buffer defined? In case there's a bounds check with `operator[]` it might be interesting to test with direct char pointers (without bounds check this should make no difference). On what CPU was the test done? (and compiled for that cpu too?). Just wondering - also depends on how good the cpu is in pipelining.

Comment: I'm using `unsigned char *bytes`, and `int *intBuffer`.  This is with a Core i5-4690K.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure compiler optimization is turned to the highest level.

I think I would give this a try:

```
unsigned char* pBytes = bytes;
uint32_t number;

for(unsigned long i = 0; i<size_tot; i+=3){
    number = *pBytes << 16;
    ++pBytes;
    number = number | (*pBytes << 8);
    ++pBytes;
    number = number | *pBytes;
    ++pBytes;

    ++intBuffer[number];
}
```

After compiling I would check how the produced assembler code looked to see if the changed actually made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read a word at a time and then extract the desired value. That should be more efficient than reading byte-by-byte

Here's a sample implementation on 64-bit little-endian systems which will read 3 64-bit values at a time

```
void count(uint8_t* bytes, int* intBuffer, uint32_t size_tot)
{
    assert(size_tot > 7);
    uint64_t num1, num2, num3;
    uint8_t *bp = bytes;
    while ((uintptr_t)bp % 8) // make sure that the pointer is properly aligned
    {
        num1 = (bp[2] << 16) | (bp[1] << 8) | bp[0];
        intBuffer[num1]++;
        bp += 3;
    }

    uint64_t* ip = (uint64_t*)bp;
    while ((uint8_t*)(ip + 2) < bytes + size_tot)
    {
        num1 = *ip++;
        num2 = *ip++;
        num3 = *ip++;

        intBuffer[num1 & 0xFFFFFF]++;
        intBuffer[(num1 >> 24) & 0xFFFFFF]++;
        intBuffer[(num1 >> 48) | ((num2 & 0xFF) << 16)]++;
        intBuffer[(num2 >> 8) & 0xFFFFFF]++;
        intBuffer[(num2 >> 32) & 0xFFFFFF]++;
        intBuffer[(num2 >> 56) | ((num3 & 0xFFFF) << 8)]++;
        intBuffer[(num3 >> 16) & 0xFFFFFF]++;
        intBuffer[num3 >> 40]++;
    }

    bp = (uint8_t*)ip;
    while (bp < bytes + size_tot)
    {
        num1 = (bp[2] << 16) | (bp[1] << 8) | bp[0];
        intBuffer[num1]++;
        bp += 3;
    }
}
```

You can check the compiler output on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwskEF8LAhuwcADAEE5CpSszqtyJoMGZih2cfOmzAN1R50qmgiBhAiCgQAHAD6BABUqgBGAJ4EmIKkquHx4TwiAGZ5LhlhBrJcMaqCeABemDGoBACUXhwA7Hzmql2qjs6uEFW19QR22KqtzbIdZt2qJQQAbAAsFSwiALb0qmvrXBk7shrTs/PRI7EJAA52ACKJKWlHXrMA7gh4DLZQ85cExDGNK7qLgAVlUEUaqgA9FDVOsmABrWyCMS2AgIJgjdG2S5%2BAwuTKCVSXYioS4uBhJHoMPDAFiYdDPbptY6zbo7Wi3VQQK4cEE8Lh8u4aTQi1S0BaQtqabm8/m0IV2UVacFS1oyuU8ExCp6dNldHL5QrEPk8Dk63j8XUzfWJa5W2R3Q5TJldNo3Fp6rrzZYxbL2x3cn0rOKAy7W17vT7c0LhM6xRoQPD23iqLhSlXJVJE/iVGp1IhNV3qdrF2YcrmxZNWy0ur1snZcSvVy211n6g7N8Otvh1iz12aGgouU0V7gLVQmAAeADE5/OLXw22XukPjaaIGP3EY00spVwJ9P5wuQR6exHbWuR/zNxtOUYd0sISWZVBG8DD7OZxnlTKJc1TxrXt2zZK8TRvd8H3cVUP0nL9j0XB0QMHAxcmHcCeFvXZRh3Mp90/Y850Q5cB1XVCjWvTDIO3aCQUlF8Y07cc4OPH8xQhYjgJXA1yPQjcmJosZ/1go9CM4i99TA0cNlkHDoKWbVAPPPtZndT0bS6IENDuWMDHjRpqxU7o3g%2BL4tMzB4c1TQYCwaZp6xZbjtjvLkeXDflBVPJUxWE6VZXcngFS8kV2LVDUAsUj0jMk3j135c0lKXLjSM0lNeydCSSw9TxWmyswpEaRhpBBKRSBYaQTFK1BpFFHtKlEcRbDkWhSoICqCsKhEQFkVoADoFgiVpWgiEFWgWEwAE4FLopYiqkJZSvKqRKtIaqpFKwQQBMUg2uWgrSDgWAkDQdZLlMsgKAgE6zs%2BYgUGYNgIhMba8g%2BVJiE2nl2tIBIFCYYgkmkFrSBO9ZMAMAB5FhKW%2BrB4TYT5YbwYhMGQAg8G8NJvswKdUZEVIgdK8JMAYb6aQSYh/qSTQMEkKRgb%2BPB1kJwqHvYIDGDwBJNsgQqyXR1AWE2qQAFoIdkkX4XEBBtJYTEMdsEWbgAORubAeAAVQAcQ2hqJDoVnisW761qnCIFhF5ZAjZ8FepMO3uVwQgSGBWQthp07ztd9NVFqpLWvawqIGO1BPdu8hKGu86QDwZBkFoCb6Fehh3s%2BhJvt%2BuWAcJkHQ7ByHocBvbSDh1hgER4v8BRtGFeFlacbxgn6aJ/FSeL8nKYBmmsBzxnmeb1my5QDnyZ5iA%2Bd%2BPBBeFsWJal5AZcdOX0cx1QldV9Xtd1sR9doQ2pBKsqTekM2Lat2PkHFCa7d6zkICdohiFd93Q5uglmshP3%2BADvag5DsOiiXSjrde6ZcnovTei4NOGc/rZ2brndY%2BcCBQxhpXTA8Ny50xWlXVGK8sbFwbsgfGdNgbEzbitDuVNu4kNasQJmLNGBD04D2Tm3N4ATwFkLaQs817z0XjcZeCs14qzVprHWQg9aSD3nNQ%2BS0Vqm3NpbJY1sy623tiYR2%2BBH7PwyB7N%2BT85CyE/kBH%2BlVGidRAAsLgvU3ZcC4LQJYXBZATRMCCKasgFhzQWqQZmtBnpH2LmtDaW0dqB33lwY2gTpCmI6qQTGH0p7lSWEAA%3D%3D%3D). Of course smart compilers may already know how to do that, but most don't. As you can see from the Godbolt link, [compilers will use a bunch of `movzx` to read the separate bytes](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Avoid+count(uint8_t*+__restrict+bytes,+int*+__restrict+intBuffer,+uint32_t+size_tot)%0A%7B%0A++++for+(uint8_t*+bp+%3D+bytes%3B+bp+%3C+bytes+%2B+size_tot%3B+bp+%2B%3D+3)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++uint32_t+num+%3D+(bp%5B2%5D+%3C%3C+16)+%7C+(bp%5B1%5D+%3C%3C+8)+%7C+bp%5B0%5D%3B%0A++++++++intBuffer%5Bnum%5D%2B%2B%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:32.26649248856957,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnative+-DNDEBUG',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc191,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnative+-DNDEBUG',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+19.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnative+-DNDEBUG',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:67.73350751143043,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) instead of reading the whole register. ICC will do a lot more loop unrolling but Clang and GCC don't

Similarly for 32-bit architectures you'll also read 3 "words" each iteration. Besides, you may need to do some manual loop unrolling instead of relying on the compiler to do that. [Here's an example on 32-bit little endian machines](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwskEF8LAhuwcADAEE5CpSszqtyJoMGZih2cfOmzAN1R50qmgiBhAiCgQAHAD6BABUqgBGAJ4EmIKkquHx4TwiAGZ5LhlhBrJcMaqCeABemDGoBACUXhwA7Hzmql2qjs6uEFW19QR22KqyzbIdZt2qJQRlFSwiALb0qssrXBmbshrTs/PRI7EJAA52ACKJKWn7XrMA7gh4DLZQ82cExDGN5%2BpcACsqgALI1VAB6CGqFZMADWtkEYlsBAQTBGqNsZz8BhcmUEqjOxFQZxcDCSPQYeGALEw6Ae3TaB1m3U2tCuqgg5w4gJ4XB51w0miFqloADZwW1NJzubzaAK7MKtKoIpLWtLZTwTAL7p0WV0cvlCsQeTw2TrePxdTN9YkLlbZNc9lMGV02pcWnquvNFnFMvbHZyfeU4n8ztani83pzQuFjrFGhA8PbeONJcrkqkCfxKjU6kQmq71O0i7M2RzYsmrZaXV6WZsuBWq5aa8z9bsm%2BGW3xaxY67NDQUXKby9wxaoTAAPABis7nFr4rdL3UHxtNUAbAPHU7n0/TSulquL0ogo/cRlUXDBC4dbZZq%2BHvNPq0bRgv4rVJ%2BfK1kW4nM73RURQ/G8l37FcDFyIcTV5Ds33cFVQJ7O93U9G0un%2BDRrljAx40aKte0jV53kwjNbmzVNBnzBpmjrJlly6M9sM1flAUFLRgIlY8ZXDOUFSFEUjylO1TW1NiI1tB8YLNVZ5XE7sJP1TCaydRTiw9TxWg0swpEaRhpEBKRSBYaQTCM1BpGFbtKlEcRbDkWgjIIUzdL0uEQFkVoADoxQiVpWgiQFWjFEwAE4QRMQExRBfSpBBIyTKkMzSAsqQjMEEATFIZykt00g4FgJA0BWM5iLICgIGK0q3mIFBmDYCITCyvJXlSYgMq5FzSASBQmGIJJpEc0hipWTADAAeRYckuqwWE2DeGa8GITBkAIPBvDSLrMEnFaRFSQajPCTAGC6qkEmIPqkk0DBJCkIbvjwFYDr0%2Br2GrAQzoyyA9JJNbUBYDKpAAWnG38gdhcQECwlh0XW2wgcuAA5S5sB4ABVABxdLbIkOgXoMhKutSycIjFIHosCV6VS8kwac5XBCBIAFZHWa6SrK5muHBKzFx4JyXL0iAitQdmavISgqrKkA8GQZBaFC%2BgWoYNqOoSLqeph/qDuGkXRomqaBty0hZtYYAFqN/BltWuHAeS7bdv2u7DtxE6jbOi7%2BuurBtYep6nZe02UHexg8ASL6IB%2Br48H%2BwGQbBiHkChx0YbWjbVAR5HUcx7GxFx2h8akQzjKJ6QSbJimZeQUVQpprz2QgBmiGIZnWZF6q8Qc7n3v53LBeF0WigqyWarq03Gua1qXFV9Xeq1p2dZWPWCEm6aLcwOazdu5LLZW1PNqN%2B3kD226hqO13kvdy6vZPpziEe57GEDzhuxDsP4Ejv6AekOP04TpPLhTnDdOSMUboyxkIHGkh86xSLolZKxNSbkxBJTU21NaYmHpvgJuLcMhs3bs3OQExVA834D3MyjQ3IgDFFwLyLMuBcFoCCLgshQqRXCrIMUsV4qkCerQJqxcjapXSplbKAsC5cEJoI6QZDXKkA2u1aOJkQRAA%3D). It can be easily [adapted for big endian](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAguYsA3VHnSq0I/RBEKCADgD6BAFSqAEYAngSYgqSqHgEePCIAZvGYZKru%2BrJcvqqCeABemL6oBACU1hwA7HyWqjWpHhlZLCIAtvSqTc1ckR2yGlUWtXX6PgSqfoEADuqyACJBoeF91oMA7gh4DJiqUGkEEwTEvsWT6lwArKoALMWqAPS3qs1MANZbgmJbBAhMo19bE/Z9MkooJVBNiKgJskGMFVEwGHhgCxMOhlrUKv1BoMOrRpnMIJMOGceFwiXMNJoKapaAA2G4VTTbQnE2hk6aUrSqTz08qM5k8MxkpbVLE1WIJJLEIk8HFC3j8YUDUVBKYK2aqXqyTHo8ozMoimq7Br%2BKKq9VueqZfzHCaK1brTbbC3DXx%2BYoQPCq3ga%2BmckJhUH8bJ5ApEEpomoYiNYnF4saehXyrXR7EtLhxvwJ%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%2BrGvKwLSBa1hgHa8X8C6nq%2BoG8WhpGsbVomoFpvF2b5rKpasAF9bNvV7apb2jjGDwQIjogE79jwc7Lpuu6Hue17PvunRUVmTgOIsoGxBBwnHMk6TIekABZABJAAFABlOHgGQZBVCMy40fwIhiAJyJcfi4E5C4In9tJwLycp6nklp2KqfzxLSuaDKuD87KGFyrmeZKsqBeq2qCAaprZcwVrpZW9y5e63r%2Bsu9yVeQUaVsqyatfcnWFv1xetOIDatsYM3fYbS3rfgO2zou6Rne%2B4rgCu2r8FYAO1NBkOIfFzyLAAJQj1Qk5TzwDHTBAdGWcc6qDzvjOQshi4cVLnJYoekQBpQMAATivJ4TwrNkGs3suUZBjlnKkE2rQMwflXLuU8t5EAXQApwLBlILgr9yHSFgbpUg/U8oOxkpcIAA%3D) like this

```
intBuffer[num1 >> 8]++;
intBuffer[((num1 & 0xFF) << 16) | (num2 >> 16)]++;
intBuffer[((num2 & 0xFFFF) << 8) | (num3 >> 24)]++;
intBuffer[num3 & 0xFFFFFF]++;
```

But for more performance you may want to sought out to a SIMD solution like SSE or AVX

Comment: @curiousguy didn't notice that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc On an uncasted pointer, it's probably a compiler error. Here, instead of `%4`, `&3` should be faster pretty much everywhere (well, maybe your compiler optimizations did this already)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I can up with in a project of mine (I used a custom error code instead of `bool`):

```cpp
template <std::endian endianness = std::endian::native, std::integral T>
constexpr auto parse_integer(std::span<std::uint8_t> buf, T& ret)
    -> bool {
  if (buf.size() < sizeof(T)) {
    return false;
  }

  for (std::size_t i{0}; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
      if constexpr (endianness == std::endian::big) {
      ret <<= 8U;
      ret |= buf[i];
    } else {
      ret >>= 8U;
      ret |= buf[i] << (8U * (sizeof(T) - 1));
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Note that the function uses some `C++20` features, like `std::endian` (it works  for any byte order!), and `std::span`. The use of `C++20` concepts can be substituted with simple `std::enable_if`s, and the span with a template parameter, like so:

```cpp
template <std::endian endianness = std::endian::native,
          typename T,
          typename Container,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>> 
inline constexpr auto parse_integer(const Container& buf, T& ret)
    -> bool {
  if (buf.size() < sizeof(T)) {
    return false;
  }

  for (std::size_t i{0}; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
      if constexpr (endianness == std::endian::big) {
      ret <<= 8U;
      ret |= buf[i];
    } else {
      ret >>= 8U;
      ret |= buf[i] << (8U * (sizeof(T) - 1));
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```