# Linux C++ ._MyFirst ._MyLast vector equivilent

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, vector, stdvector

On Windows using VS2013 I am using ._MyFirst and ._MyLast to get the pointers to the first and last elements of the vector for a fast manipulation through pointer incrementing.

```
vec._MyFirst->element = anotherElement;
vec._MyFrist++;
```

On Linux though this does not seem to there but I assume there must be an equivalent of it. Would anyone know what it is?

I know this should not be done, but in debug mode using them has almost no overheads thus allowing me to do tests quickly on massive vectors.

_MyFirst is the direct pointer that is used by the vector itself to the first element and _MyLast points tot he last element. Instead of using an iterator it's much faster to go through the vector my incrementing the pointer memory address thus is why I am using them. Also if the vector ever gets resized the ._MyFirst and ._MyLast will always point to first and last elements. On linux their not present under that name.

Thank you

Comment: This is massively non-standard. What's wrong with `vec.begin();` and `vec.end()`? The iterators will just be very slim wrappers around pointers anyway, almost everything inlined away. (In fact, they may even *be* pointers). There *are* standard ways to get pointers into the data, for instance [`vec.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), but they may not be appropriate for what you are doing.

Comment: @bob as a guess, the OP noticed it was faster ... in debug, where the iterators are instrumented with extra checks.  Then did not check in release.

Comment: That is correct! As I am doing my test in debug mode and working with point clouds that have +600000 points it can get really slow, so using _MyFirst and _MyLast does less checks and has a much lower overhead :)

Comment: @user1031204 Ok, makes some sense then. Have you tried profiling your optimised release build?

Comment: I actually have and even with release I found minor speed improvement using them but it's super minor and no worth it. But while in debug it's a difference between getting  0.2fps and 19fps working with point clouds.

Comment: @user1031204 If you're worried about speed while being able to debug, you could always try a "release-with-debug-info" build configuration (e.g. `g++ -O2 -g`). While debugging gets a _bit_ more difficult, in my experience it is usually a good compromise.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without any description of what you expect `_MyFirst()` or `_MyLast()` to do.  I'm guessing that `vec` is a `std::vector` of some sort?

Comment: _MyFirst and _MyLast are not methods, their actual pointers used by the vector, they do error or bound checking thus a very very fast and I use them to go through the vectors that a lot of elements inside. If vector is resized they are updated automatically.

Comment: @user1031204 well if you're already using hacks I'm not gonna try to convince you otherwise. Your answer is "it depends on the C++ library implementation". In libstdc++ it's "_M_impl._M_start" (and end) which you might not have access to but you can just reinterpret_cast an offset to the vector if you're so inclined.

Comment: Sorry for being stubborn. Looking at the source of stl_vector I did find the "_M_impl._M_start" but upon using it I get the "_M_impl’ is inaccessible" error.

Comment: @user1031204 like I said, calculate the offset and cast it manually then, since you're so obsessed with this hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just get a pointer to the start of the internal container and increment it to get the end.

```
auto fPtr = vec.data();
auto ePtr = fPtr + vec.size();
```

Comment: The vectors I work with get resized a lot thus _MyFirst and _MyLast are always kept up to date

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see that you're looking for performance with debug info. One way (as you are doing) is to compile a debug build with no optimisations and then seek to 'optimise source code by hand' by writing nonstandard code.

Another of course is to write standards-conforming code and simply turn on optimisations and debug output.

I did an illustration of the costs of writing correct code some time back when answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566603/c-fastest-way-to-convert-byte-to-unsigned-int/34567122#34567122)

TL;DR - there is zero overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the pointers with:

```
auto sPtr = &vec.front();
auto lastPtr = &vec.back();
```

The end pointer is one position after the last element:

```
auto ePtr = lastPtr + 1;
```

Note: For the data() method you need c++11 or later. VS 2013 suports it partly, but under Linux you might need to tell him to use that standard.